# Highcharts click event not working with npm standalone module

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, npm, commonjs

I recently migrated an existing ReactJS component that renders a Highcharts chart into CommonJS format. Accordingly, the Highcharts library is now included via ES6 import, as supposed to via the `<script>` tag.

Most of the functionality migrated without issue except for the click event handlers bound to the line chart points. The follow is the pertinent snippet of the chart options hash:

```
this.chart = Highcharts.chart({
  chart: {
    renderTo: this.chartId,
    type: 'line'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    line: {
      allowPointSelect: true,
      point: {
        events: {
          click: function(e) {
            // some action
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    enabled: true, 
    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span>{point.meta}'
  },
  ...
});
```

This was confirmed to be working prior to migrating to CommonJS format. The only difference in code between the pre- and post-migration was in the instantiation:

```
$('#' + this.chartId).highcharts({...});
```

When clicking on a point, the following error appears:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property target of #<Event> which has only a getter
```

Interestingly, clicking on a tooltip also triggers the same error (even though no event handlers were explicitly bound to it in the chart config). Perhaps a Highcharts-internal event handler?

I'm using Highcharts v2.4.2 (via npm).

The following are the file imports:

```
  import $ from 'jquery';
  import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
```

As mentioned, most of the existing functionality is working fine (chart renders, animations working, etc.) - just an issue with setting the event handlers.

Comment: I am having the same issue. In my case, I have tried the simplest of examples. Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-events-click/. I am using React 15.1.0. higcharts 4.2.5, and webpack 1.12.

Comment: In my case, it turns out that the highcharts dependency downloaded via npm was the problem. My workaround was to simply download the Highcharts JS manually and include it via <script src="..." >